# mount a partition on an lvm partition

Tags: xen, lvm, mount

I have a xen dom0 server (named virtserver), which contains a guest machine, let's call it "virtguest".

The virtguest used to be a physical machine earlier, and the whole old disk (with several partitions) is located on a lvm volume on virtserver now (not made by me). How can I access (mount) sda1 on virtguest from virtserver?

Theoretically it should be located on /dev/vgvirt/virtguest-disk/sda1 but obviously that does not work.

Right now, virtguest gets the whole /dev/vgvirt/virtguest-disk as /dev/sda and then it mounts the partitions on that disk after boot as /dev/sda1, dev/sda2 etc, but now I need to extract information on sda1 from "outside".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what I have to do is run block-attach:

```
root@virtserver:# xm block-attach 0 phy:/dev/vgvirt/virtguest-disk xvda w
root@virtserver:# mount /dev/xvda1 /mnt
```

or use xl instead of xm if it is xen > 4.1

Comment: Block-Attach is meant to attach a disk to a DomU. Ok - Dom0 is a priviledged DomU - but this is too complicated - and you still would have to use `kpartx -av /dev/xvda` to use/mount the partitons on that disk.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [kpartx](http://linux.die.net/man/8/kpartx)

Add disk mappings:

```
kpartx -a  /dev/vgvirt/virtguest-disk
```

See if you can find the vg.

```
vgscan
```

then vgchange and mount (for example under /mnt)

```
vgchange -a y yourVGname
mount /dev/yourVGname/yourLV /mnt
```

If you run LVM on the box from where you try to do this, and the names of the VG:s are the same, then you might get problems.

Here is a good howto: http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Access_a_LVM-based_DomU_disk_outside_of_the_domU

or you could consider using [guestfish](http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/linux/kvm/virt-resize/RHEL/LVM/kvm-linux-expanding-a-lvm-guest-file-system-using-virt-resize/).

Comment: But there is only LVM on the dom0, not the domU. But the Howto lead me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: `kpartx` is enough. From the description there is no VG/LV on the DomU - so no need to do any extra tricks after kpartx.